# Recognise user without using IP

Tags: php

I need to grant access to user with or without credentials.
I have tried the `SERVER[remote_addr]` but it didn't work due to dynamic IP used in the company.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three easy steps:

1. Make a static page (unrelated to your application, say it's at `http://company.com/boss`) that redirects to your application using some special URL parameters (e.g. have it redirect the browser to `http://company.com/application/index.php?super_secret=IAMTHEBOSS`).
2. Have your application recognize the `super_secret=IAMTHEBOSS` variable and allow access without credentials.
3. If someone obtains unauthorized access to the application (e.g. by simply hitting the `http://company.com/boss` URL), explain to your boss that they should fire themselves instead of you because this massive security hole was left open at their insistence.

Comment: easier said than done :P but thanks anyway and all the other guys for trying to answer...I will at least try to login manually on his system and store a cookie for longest possible period

Answer (score 0):

There's no good solution for this other than using credentials, or perhaps, try manually "injecting" a cookie to your boss's browser, but that would probably be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Explain to your boss that this is not possible without creating a ***major security hole***.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cookie on your bosse's machine but this would expire at some point so credentials would need to be put in again when that happened. If you have no way of locking down who is accessing your application it is a massive security risk to not use credentials. Doing this by IP address is not secure either as IP addresses can be easily spoofed.